# How to create Kotlin annotation class with getters and setters specific autogenerate

Tags: java, android, kotlin, annotations

I transform any part of dump to Kotlin interface for access:

```
interface IDumpData {
        //  block 0
        val id: UInt
            get() = blocks[0].getUIntAt(0)
        val crc: UByte
            get() = blocks[0][4].toUByte()
        //unsigned char unused_0[11];
    
        // block 60
        val version: UShort
            get() = blocks[60].getUShortAt(0)
        val type: UByte
            get() = blocks[60][2].toUByte()
        val data1: UInt
            get() = blocks[60].getUIntAt(2 + 1)
        val data2: UShort
            get() = blocks[60].getUShortAt(2 + 1 + 4)
        val data3: UShort
            get() = blocks[60].getUShortAt(2 + 1 + 4 + 2)
        val data4: UShort
            get() = blocks[60].getUShortAt(2 + 1 + 4 + 2 + 2)
        val size: UShort
            get() = blocks[60].getUShortAt(2 + 1 + 4 + 2 + 2 + 2)
        //unsigned char unused_60;
    
        var blocks: Array<ByteArray>// Array(64) { ByteArray(16) }
    }
```

How can I create a Kotlin annotation class that sets getter and setter automatically based on field position and type of fields?
So that in the end it looks something like this:

```
@DumpToClass
interface IDumpData {
    //  block 0
    @Block(0) val id: UInt
    @Block(0) val crc: UByte
    //unsigned char unused_0[11];

    // block 60
    @Block(60) val  version: UShort
    @Block(60) val type: UByte
    @Block(60) val data1: UInt
    @Block(60) val data2: UShort
    @Block(60) val data3: UShort
    @Block(60) val data4: UShort
    @Block(60) val size: UShort
    //unsigned char unused_60;

    var blocks: Array<ByteArray>// Array(64) { ByteArray(16) }
}
```

Comment: Hopefully someone will prove me wrong, but I don't think you can do this with just an annotation processor. You'll need a compiler plugin, which is much more difficult. See https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/kotlinconf2018/slides/5_Writing%20Your%20First%20Kotlin%20Compiler%20Plugin.pdf and https://medium.com/@heyitsmohit/writing-kotlin-compiler-plugin-with-arrow-meta-cf7b3689aa3e as starting points.

Comment: Thanks for this starting points! I'll trying it.